# RecursionError when python copy.deepcopy

Tags: python, getattr

I have a problem in python.

I have a class whis custom `__getattr__`

```
class ChoiceNumToName(object):
    def __init__(self, django_choice_tuple):
        self.ods_choice_tuple = django_choice_tuple
        self.choice_data = {}
        self.choice_point = -1
        for choice_value, choice_name in django_choice_tuple:
            self.choice_data.setdefault(choice_name, choice_value)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.choice_data:
            return self.choice_data[item]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("no attribute %s" % item)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ods_choice_tuple)

    def __iter__(self):
        self.choice_point = -1
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.choice_point += 1
        try:
            return self.ods_choice_tuple[self.choice_point]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration()
```

when I execute this

```
a = ChoiceNumToName((
    (1, "running"),
    (2, "stopped"),
))
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

It raise `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

To fix this problem is sample, change `__getattr__` function to this

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item == "__setstate__":
        raise AttributeError(item)
    if item in self.choice_data:
        return self.choice_data[item]
    else:
        raise AttributeError("no attribute %s" % item)
```

It work well.

I know this solution from here 
https://github.com/python-babel/flask-babel/commit/8319a7f44f4a0b97298d20ad702f7618e6bdab6a

But can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 10):

TLDR: your `__getattr__` is called before `choice_data` has been added to the instance dictionary which causes it to endlessly recurse. A better way to address the problem is to immediately raise AttributeError for any attributes beginning with `__` to catch any other special or internal attributes.

This happens because when an object is copied the `__init__` method is not called. Rather, a new, empty object is created. This new object has an empty `__dict__`. Python's pickle protocol (which is also used for the copy module) has a hook `__setstate__` that allows customization of applying a state (normally just the contents for `__dict__` but, e.g. if `__getstate__` is provided, it can be any object). To see if that hook is present `hasattr(newobj, '__setstate__')` is called which, since there isn't any `__setstate__` in the MRO nor in the `__dict__` causes your `__getattr__` to be called. Your `__getattr__` then tries to access `self.choice_data` but, as we've noted earlier the `__dict__` is currently empty. This causes the `__getattr__` method to be invoked again to get the `choice_data` attribute which starts the infinite recursion.

Special casing `__setstate__` stops the recursion from being triggered by bailing out early for the lookup of `__setstate__`. When that fails, the default mechanism for copying takes effect which initializes the new object's `__dict__` from the state. In my mind special casing only `__setstate__` is not the best solution. I think it is best to immediately raise AttributeError for any special or internal attributes, i.e. the ones that begin with `__`, since that prevents other strange situations from occurring. Another possibility is to avoid using attribute lookup within `__getattr__` by writing `self.__dict__['choice_data']` or `object.__getattribute__(self, 'choice_data')`. You can also ensure that `choice_data` will be present by implementing `__new__` and assigning it to the object there.

Answer (score 1):

The methods `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` are used in pickling operations. Why does this matter? From the [Python docs on copying](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html):

> Classes can use the same interfaces to control copying that they use to control pickling.

By defining a `__setstate__` that refers to itself you've created a recursive object, hence the RecursionError.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this issue myself. Basically, any class with `__getattr__` that tries to access a member variable will hit an infinite recursion and throw a `RecursionError` when using `copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy`. Geoff Reedy's answer explains it pretty well, but I found a nicer writeup [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html).

Interstingly, this did not happen in Python 2, because of a bug in `hasattr()` that caused it to return False on any exception.

Adding the check against `__setstate__` will solve the specific issue, but a more general approach is to guard against the state variable itself.

In your case, that would be:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item == "choice_data":  # Object state not initialized
        raise AttributeError(item)
    if item in self.choice_data:
        return self.choice_data[item]
    else:
        raise AttributeError("no attribute %s" % item)
```